# Do not you know how to take the capture of the arbitrary URL in a server-side? (with Chromium )

Tags: google-chrome, capture

As for Google chrome, a site captures a reading history if I think personally. 
May not you acquire capture with the library?
like this site;[link text](http://img.simpleapi.net/)

Comment: Dude. You made my brain segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to screen capture a website that someone submits, like the thumbnails in the site you linked to?
The simplest way would be to use a service like [one of these.](http://websitetips.com/tools/#online-screenshots) And then write a script to grab the image.

Comment: yes ! "how to screen capture a website " with chronium library

Comment: Ok - I didn't address the chromium part. With that you're just rendering the page with webkit. I'm sure there's a library for perl, et al. to do so - but I'm not familiar with any.

Comment: Thanks! a lot ! I search that library for perl you said by google